# ECS set port mapping via Environment variable

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

ECS task definition only seems to allow integer values in port mapping. I would like to set an environment variable based off a command and then expose that env variable port. Is this possible in ECS? If not, are there any workarounds?

I can do it in docker-compose as follows

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    environment:
      - SERVICE_SIDECAR=true
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: /root/prom/prometheus.yml
        target: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"

  prometheus-proxy:
    image: consul-envoy
    ports:
      - ${PROXY_PORT}:${PROXY_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
```

Env file

```
PROXY_PORT=$(curl localhost:8500/v1/agent/services | jq '."ip-172-31-10-76:prom_prometheus_1:9090-sidecar-proxy".Port')
```

Got an update from AWS Support:
This feature is not available in ECS yet.